# EF Core ChangeTracker() current and original values are the same for Modified entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, audit-logging

I'm creating an audit trail using EF Core's change tracker, and for every entity that has the state `Added`, `Modified` or `Deleted`, I create a new audit entity to insert into my `Audit` table. I want to take a snapshot of what I had before an `UPDATE` and capture it in JSON and do the same for a snapshot of the entity after the `UPDATE`.

```
var entityType = this.Model.FindEntityType(dbEntry.Entity.GetType());
var originalObjectProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var currentObjectProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var property in entityType.GetProperties())
{
    originalObjectProperties.Add(property.GetColumnName().ToUpper(), dbEntry.OriginalValues[property.Name]);
    currentObjectProperties.Add(property.GetColumnName().ToUpper(), dbEntry.CurrentValues[property.Name]);
}
```

`dbEntry` is the entity entry from the change tracker. These give me the same exact JSON though. In my tests I have an `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, and this is what ends up in my `BEFORE_JSON` and `AFTER_JSON` in my database for my `UPDATE`:

```
{
    "WORK_REQUEST_KEY": 2,
    "PROJECT_NAME": "This has now been updated",
    "WR_TYPE_KEY": 2
}
{
    "WORK_REQUEST_KEY": 2,
    "PROJECT_NAME": "This has now been updated",
    "WR_TYPE_KEY": 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this should be equivalent, but with slightly less complexity;

```cs
var originalObjectProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
var currentObjectProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var property in dbEntry.Properties)
{
    var key = property.Metadata.GetColumnName().ToUpper();
    originalObjectProperties.Add(key, property.OriginalValue);
    currentObjectProperties.Add(key, dbEntry.CurrentValues[property.Metadata]);
}
```

But what you get out of your change tracker, depends on what you put into it. Were your entities loaded from the database and then changed? Or re-attached as modified?

The most reliable way to audit original values would be in a database trigger, or perhaps using some other built-in database feature.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid database triggers, but in my tests I'm creating a new `WORK_REQUEST` entity and inserting it into the database. I then get that entity out of the database using it's key, change a the `PROJECT_NAME` property and update it in the database. Finally I delete the entity from the database.

Comment: You could first obtain the entity from the database and then update it. In that way the changetracker will be aware of the previous values. Anyway the only 100% reliable mechanism is thru triggers on the database